# "drag and drop sidebar modules" Is it possible to do this with Jquery and Ajax (or at all)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, module, sidebar

I'm trying to create modules that users can drag and drop from the sidebar into the main content window.  These modules are basic text boxes, video uploaders, ext.

I pretty much want to do the exact same thing you would do on a **Squidoo** page when you're creating a lens. **The only difference is that I don't want the page to reload**, and I want the user to just be able to drag and drop.

For example if they wanted to add a text box to the page, then they would just drag the text that said "text" from the sidebar into the main content window and then they could edit straight from there, and move the box up or down on the main page if they wanted to.

I've been searching everywhere for how to do this, but I've never seen it done this way.  Does anybody know how to do this.  I could really use the help!

Comment: It's definitely possible, I think it would take some work though.
Have you looked at jQuery UI?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Portlets](http://host.sonspring.com/portlets/) might be just what you need.

Alternatively, [WebDeveloper+ has a tutorial on DIY portlets.](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/collpasible-drag-drop-panels/)

Comment: Yeah I've looked at that site a lot, and I would probably have to use a combination of jquery UI's like the sortable, draggable, drop, ext.  But I don't know how to make it work the way I want it to...